# recuperar valor de DropdownButton StatefulWidget en StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter, dropdownlist

Hola buen día estoy intentando pasar el valor que se selecciona en el  DropdownButton para pasarlo como valor en un onTap para crear un nuevo elemento, mi problema es que no he podido obtener el valor cuando eligen una opción, mi  DropdownButton es un stateful y donde lo mando a llamar es un stateless, y donde necesito que recupere el valor es un onTap que se encuentra dentro de un listado en el widget ticketWidget que es donde se crean los nuevos elementos con valores de la data u otros elementos, pero en el valor tipoVenta necesito que según el item seleccionado del  DropdownButton tome ese valor, si es 1, que el valor de tipoVenta sea 1, 2 o 3 dependiendo su elección en el DropdownButton:

```
 class TicketPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final RutaModel rutas;

  int ticket_id;

  TicketPage({Key key, @required this.rutas}) {

    // var ticket_id = obten_id_ticket(rutas.idRuta, rutas.usuRuta, rutas.idCte);
    // print('ultima linea');
  }


  obten_id_ticket(int id_rutin, int id_suring, int id_ctein) async {

    int res = await DBXicaras.db
        .checar_ticket(rutas.idRuta, rutas.usuRuta, rutas.idCte)
        .then((idtickes) {
      ticket_id = idtickes;
    });

    return res;

  }


  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    obten_id_ticket(rutas.idRuta, rutas.usuRuta, rutas.idCte);

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange[300],
        title: Text('Ticket de venta'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                title: Text('ID Ruta: ${rutas.idRuta.toString()}'),
                subtitle: Text('Cliente: ${rutas.nomCte}'),
                leading: Text('Tipo: ${rutas.tipoRuta}'),
              ),
              // Divider(
              //   height: 30.0,
              // ),
              SelectedType(),
              Divider(
                height: 30.0,
              ),
              ticketWidget(),
              Divider(
                height: 30.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  ticketWidget() {

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: DBXicaras.db.getAllProducts(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Container();
        }
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(children: [
            ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: 200.0,
              height: 50.0,
              child: RaisedButton.icon(
                  color: Colors.orange[300],
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Detallepage(
                                  ticket_id: ticket_id,
                                )));
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.money),
                  label: Text(
                    'Total:',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                  )),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
                ProductModel product = snapshot.data[i];
                return Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.local_drink,
                          color: Colors.orange[400],
                        ),
                        title: Text('Producto: ${product.nomProd}'),
                        subtitle: Text('Precio:  ${product.precioProd}'),
                        onTap: () async {
                          double cantidad = 1;
                          double subtotal = cantidad * product.precioProd;
                          double iva = subtotal * (product.porcIva / 100);
                          double ieps = subtotal * (product.porcIeps / 100);
                          double total = subtotal + iva + ieps;
                          //si llegase a haber descuentos me los envia el servidor y hago la operacion aquí y se agrega en el insert en vez de 0
                          final resp = await DBXicaras.db.newDetalle(
                              new DetalleModel(
                                  clvProd: product.claveProd,
                                  nomProd: product.nomProd,
                                  precio: product.precioProd,
                                  idTicket: ticket_id,
                                  cantidad: 1,
                                  tipoVenta: value,
                                  subtotal: subtotal,
                                  prodIva: iva,
                                  prodIeps: ieps,
                                  prodRetiva: 0,
                                  prodRetisr: 0,
                                  total: total,
                                  unidad: product.unidad,
                                  porcDesc: 0,
                                  descProd: 0));
                          final deta_ll =
                              await DBXicaras.db.getDetalleId(ticket_id);
                          print('RESPUESTA A CONSULTAS DE DETALLES ${deta_ll}');
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ]),
        );
      },
    );
  }

}


class SelectedType extends StatefulWidget {

  int value;

  SelectedType({

    Key key,
    @required this.value,
  }) : super(key: key);


  @override

  _SelectedTypeState createState() => _SelectedTypeState();

}


class _SelectedTypeState extends State<SelectedType> {

  int _value = 1;

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return DropdownButton(
        value: _value,
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text("Venta"),
            value: 1,
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text("Cambio"),
            value: 2,
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Dañado"), value: 3),
          DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Cortesia"), value: 4)
        ],
        onChanged: (int value) {
          setState(() {
            _value = value;
            print(value);
          });
        });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para recuperar el valor de tu dropdownButton sería que le enviaras un callBack como parámetro. Tu clase SelectedType quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
class SelectedType extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(int value) onChangeValue;
  final int value;
  SelectedType({
    Key key,
    @required this.value,
    this.onChangeValue,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SelectedTypeState createState() => _SelectedTypeState();
}

class _SelectedTypeState extends State<SelectedType> {
  int _value = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton(
        value: _value,
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text("Venta"),
            value: 1,
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text("Cambio"),
            value: 2,
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Dañado"), value: 3),
          DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Cortesia"), value: 4)
        ],
        onChanged: (int value) {
          setState(() {
            _value = value;
            print(value);
            widget.onChangeValue(value);
          });
        });
  }
}
```

Y en tu clase TicketPage obtendrías el valor que te esta enviando tu dropdownButton de la siguiente manera

```
SelectedType(
   onChangeValue: (newValue){
      setState(() {
         value = newValue;
      });
   },
)
```

Como la solución que te estoy proponiendo hace uso de setState debes de cambiar tu clase TicketPage de StatelessWidget a StatefulWidget y claro crear esa variable value de tipo int en tu misma clase TicketPage para obtener el valor que te esta devolviendo tu DropdownButton.

Comment: Gracias lo intentare